# Приложение для устройства на первую работу

Tags: c#, работа

Доброго времени суток.
Ситуация такая, собираюсь устраиваться на junior .NET разработчика, это будет первая работа. Хочу написать какое-то осмысленное и более-менее полезное приложение (или даже два), выложить на гитхаб и добавить ссылку в резюме. Считаю, что это увелит шансы попасть на работу, т.к. работодатель увидит хоть какой-то реальный код, ну или как минимум увеличит шансы попасть на собеседование.

Собственно я хочу, чтобы вы предложили идею такого приложения, оно должно быть не очень сложным, уровня джуниора. Приложение будет десктопным, писаться будет на WinForms или WPF. 
Сам вот пока ничего интересного не придумал, кроме банальных органайзеров или менеджеров задач ничего в голову пока не пришло.
Может вы посоветуете?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Клиент для hashcode.ru (с треем и оповещениями о новых темах)
2. Скриншотер (для снятия скриншотов с экрана)
3. игру "Жизнь" Конвея (она простенькая совсем)

Это то, что первое в голову пришло. Может потом дополню еще...

Comment: К п.1: можно рискнуть сделать а-ля Hashcode Reader для Metro - возможно, оценится в свете текущих трендов.

Answer (score 6):

Если Вы можете сами спроектировать и разработать приложение, то это уже немножко выше junior'а.

Что можно посоветовать:

- Сортировщик картинок. Сортирует картинки на группы по определенным признакам (размер, формат, цветовая гамма), поиск дубликатов.
- Преобразователи текстов. Например, есть много старых книг/статей в текстовом формате с текстовой графикой. Этот текст анализируется и на выходе получается более-менее приличный pdf.
- Простой графический (векторный) редактор.

Answer (score 6):

Сделайте какую-нибудь настольную игру, шашки там или шахматы. Или Го, модная штука же! Искусственный интеллект делать не надо, это сложно и не для джуниора. Пусть играют двое игроков. Можно и сеть прикрутить, кстати, в качестве продвинутой фичи.

Или например многосторонний чат-клиент (это уже непросто!).

Answer (score 6):

Я считаю что ваше приложение должно уметь следующее

-показать работу с базовыми конструкциями и типа языка
-работать с СУБД (наверное использовать ORM без этого никуда)
-работа с сетью
-работа с XML

Из всего этого мне кажется что проще всего написать клиента к какому либо популярному веб-сервису или соц сети - получать сохранять и обрабатывать данные. Возможно какой то анализатор активности в Твитер или ВК. Полет фантазии большой но главное использовать в этом приложении мэйнстрим технологии.

Answer (score 5):

Напишите, небольшой клиент для Вконтакта (например, получение списка друзей):

- покажете умение работать с WebAPI
- подключите к солюшену сторонние библиотеки с помощью NuGet
- добавьте логирование с помощью NLog (пакет NLog)
- сохраняйте данные в базе данных (SQL, SQLite, Mongo, etc) - покажите, что умете работать с БД
- сохраняйте настройки приложения в XML

В общем, огромный простор для показа (и закрепления) своих навыков.

Answer (score 5):

Напиши небольшой чат(клиент-сервер).
В нем покажешь работу с сетью, многопоточность, разработка GUI, можно подключить работу с SQL.

Answer (score 5):

Я в свое время писал геоинформационную систему на plain C - это сразу после окончания Универа.

Когда пересаживался на Java писал апплет-калькулятор.

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант - игру тетрис, танчики, бота для браузерной игрушки - довольно интересно может быть.